# How to draw a perturbed circle?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How do I draw a Perturbed Circle?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

e=0.3

ylist = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)

R=1+e*np.sin(2*ylist)


circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0),R)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_artist(circle1)

plt.axis([-3, 3, -3, 3])
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code as such.

Comment: How can I do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a list as radius to a `Circle`. 
There might be other methods to draw a "disturbed" circle, but I find it very intuitive to draw a parametric curve using `plt.contour()`.

The parametric curve for a perfect circle with radius `R` would be

```
0 = x**2 + y**2 - R
```

while in this case it's

```
0 = x**2 + y**2 - 1 -e*np.sin(2*np.arctan(y/x)) =: f
```

So we can plot `f(x,y)` and in the call to `contour(X,Y,Z, levels)` we set `levels` to `0`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

e=0.3

x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2 - 1 -e*np.sin(2*np.arctan(y/x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.contour(X,Y, f(X, Y), 0)

plt.axis([-2, 2, -2, 2])
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]